# DAO não injetando com @EJB annotation

Tags: java, java-ee, wildfly, ejb

Estou fazendo uma requisição para *"/contador/{id}"* pelo PostMan e quando o código chega em *notificaoDAO.contador(id)*, recebo a mensagem de erro dizendo que *notificacaoDAO* é **null**.

PS: Estou usando Wildfly 11 com Eclipse Oxygen

**Controller**

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("ejb/notificacao")
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class NotificacaoControladorEJB {


    SmartJava smartjava = new SmartJava();
    @EJB
    NotificacaoDAOEJB notificacaoDAO;


    @GET
    @Produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    @Path("/contador/{id}")
    public Notificacao contadorGet(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        long quantidade;
        try {
            quantidade = notificacaoDAO.contador(id);

            return new Notificacao(quantidade);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            quantidade = 0;
            System.err.println(smartjava.getFullStackTrace(e));

            return new Notificacao(quantidade);
        }
    }
```

**DAO**

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;


@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class NotificacaoDAOEJB {

    //private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    SmartJava sj = new SmartJava();



    public Notificacao Salvar(Notificacao notificacao) {

        try {
            this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            this.entityManager.persist(notificacao);
            this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(sj.getFullStackTrace(e));

        } finally {
            //this.entityManager.close();
        }

        return notificacao;
    }

    public void Alterar(Notificacao notificacao){

        this.entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        this.entityManager.merge(notificacao);
        this.entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        //this.entityManager.close();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Notificacao> Listar(){
        return this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Notificacao a ORDER BY a.dtcad").getResultList();
    }

    public Notificacao GetNotificacao(int nrseq) {
        return this.entityManager.find(Notificacao.class, nrseq);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public long contador(int nrsequsuario) {
        try {
            return (long) this.entityManager.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(a) FROM Notificacao a "
                    + "WHERE a.visualizado = false AND a.useralvo.nrseq = :usuario ORDER BY a.dtcad")
                    .setParameter("usuario", nrsequsuario).getSingleResult();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println(sj.getFullStackTrace(e));
            return 0;
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: Você consegue ver se o seu ejb é instalado com sucesso? Isso aparece nos logs da console quando o Wildfly é iniciado (com o pacote) ou quando você adiciona o projeto.

Comment: Acredito que voce não precisa esta com a anotação @LocalBean na classe NotificacaoDAOEJB.